# adding controls value to datagridview rows dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using this code to adding a row dynamically in DataGridView:

```html
frmInvoice.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", cmbType1.Text);
```

the problem is here that value of cmbType1.Text is not showing in DGV cell.
I tried this code:

```html
frmInvoice.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "some test");
```

and it was worked. "some test" is showing up in DGW cell. I tried other controls value like labels, textboxes and etc but thier value is not showing in DGW cell. (sorry for my bad english)

what I missed? about combobox I tried every properties (SelectedText,Text,SelectedValue.toString and etc ...)
what should I do?

Comment: string test = cmbType1.Text;
frmInvoice.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", test);

Comment: Does that control `cmbType1` have a value at the time of adding row? On what event, you are adding the row?

Comment: problem is solved ... it was because if filling data table. I used a fill query unnecessary, I removed it and it fixed.